# Android-BluetoothSPPLibrary создание нескольких объектов

Tags: android, bluetooth

Нашел на github такую библиотеку https://github.com/akexorcist/Android-BluetoothSPPLibrary
В принципе, достаточно известная, поэтому заставить работать ее в коде не было проблем. Но теперь мне нужно использовать несколько объектов этого класса, поэтому я создаю объект `private lateinit var bt2: BluetoothSPP` и все компилируется и нет проблем в работе на телефоне, но когда я добавляю запуск bt2 в коде, как в примере на gitlab

`bt2.setupService()
 bt2.startService(BluetoothState.DEVICE_OTHER)`

то все нормально, до того момента как в коде не запускаются эти сервисы и программа просто вылетает. Знает ли кто-нибудь в чем проблема?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ был найден тут https://github.com/akexorcist/Android-BluetoothSPPLibrary/issues/54
В данной библиотеке нельзя иметь несколько подключений к устройствам